# oracle sql - to store 4000 characters in a column of my DB table

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, spring-mvc

In my web application, I am saving some Text message in a COLUMN of a DB table(Oracle). Earlier the VARCHAR2 length(maximum length) is (500 BYTE). Now the client has asked me to increase the maximum length to 4000 characters.
Is it possible to save 4000 char in a column of a DB table or do we need to save it as BLOB.
Which gives better performance?
Can anyone please clarify on this?

Comment: Why do you want a `varchar2(4000)` column? This smells of a horrifically bad design.

Comment: @Jack - so do we need to use BLOB for a better performance?

Comment: Again: why do you want a `varchar2(4000)` column?

Comment: I need to allow the user to enter upto 4000 characters

Comment: Okay, then, **why do you need to allow the user to enter up to 4,000 characters**? Think about your design.

Comment: @JackManey: when storing "*messages*" it seems like a valid requirement to store 4000 characters.

Comment: The field was storing text entered by a user that could be an unknown size. The first implementation set the size to 500 characters.  4000 was suggested as a quick work around, but the final solution needed to have an unbounded max size, so would need a BLOB.  Performance is not really an issue because the field will only be read/updated a few times a day.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE t1(id NUMBER, doc CLOB);    DECLARE
vClob VARCHAR(15000);
BEGIN
vClob := 'messages, mesage1......';
insert into t1
values(100,vClob);
END;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check [CLOB](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CLOB). For saving large Text oracle recommends CLOB.

> A CLOB (Character Large Object) is an Oracle data type that can hold
>   up to 4 GB of data. CLOBs are handy for storing text.

Comment: So [this](http://www.fordevs.com/2011/04/how-to-convert-the-data-type-varchar2-to-clob-in-oracle.html) helped me to fix my problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 7):

Oracle has a limit of 4000 ***bytes*** for a `VARCHAR2` column and there is no way to workaround that limit.

So you can only store 4000 characters in a `VARCHAR2` column if you are using a *single-byte* characterset.

If you are using UTF8 or any other multi-byte characterset you might not be able to store 4000 *characters* (as some characters require more than one byte). Defining the column as `VARCHAR2(4000 Char)` will **not** overcome that limit.

If you are indeed using a multi-byte characterset you will have to use a `CLOB` column otherwise you cannot store 4000 characters (as suggested by gTito).

If you are using a single byte characterset then you can get away with a `VARCHAR2(4000 Char)` column.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search on that filed by sql query, it must be varchar2.
otherwise clob/blob is better because it takes